# An error in Leo's Tecniques for nuclear and subnuclear physics experiment?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics

I need to use the breamsstrahlung energy loss for an electron for some calculations.

I am looking at Leo's "*Techniques for nuclear and subnuclear physics experiment*". At page 37, the energy loss is given by:

$$-\left( \dfrac{dE}{dx} \right)_{rad} = N \int_0^{\nu_0} h\nu \dfrac{d\sigma}{d\nu}(E_0,\nu)d\nu$$

where $E_0$ is the *total* initial energy of the electron and $\nu_0=\dfrac{E_0}{h}$.

I do not understand the lower limit: if, as written at page 36, $E_0$ is the total energy (and so the sum of the mass and of the kinetic energy), the lower limit should be the electron mass $m_e$, this energy cannot be radiated away.

Comment: I don't see a book (in English, anyway) with that title. I see instead the book "_Techniques for nuclear and particle physics experiment_". Can you confirm that the book I reference has the same material for this section as the book you reference?

Comment: @probably_someone yes it has the same material

Comment: Also, it's not the lower limit that's the problem, it's the upper limit - we're integrating over the radiated photon's frequency, and there's nothing wrong with radiating an amount of energy smaller than the electron's mass-energy. The problem comes when you try to radiate away _more_ energy than the electron's kinetic energy, so intuitively the upper limit should be $\nu_0-m_e/h$.